# Selenium log-in on pop-up webpage without HTML

Tags: python, selenium, popup

In my Selenium program, I use a google-chrome driver to access and log into my account on this [webpage](https://trade.swissquote.ch/bank_security/login/RedirectAtLogin.action?trackPageId=jxlmymbqf8nwaicll48mrndol*3973861513&cookieId=undefined&sessionId=jxlmymbqf8nwaicll48mrndol). The problem is that the log-in webpage is a program with a pop-up window and without any HTML code I can grab. Therefore I don't know how to type in my credentials.

I have looked around and have seen several proposals with 'actions' like

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys('skdkds')
actions.perform()
```

But the problem is that it doesn't type in anything, it only places the cursor in the first field. I guess this is part of the security of the program, but by being able to place the cursor in the right place, I should be able to send keys to the driver and then move along with a tab command. But I don't know how.

For a reproducible example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import time
import glob
import os

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(link_mentionned_above) //then I am blocked
```

**Updated**

As mentionned by Azy_Crw4282, the problem is here handling alerts, however the driver doesn't recognize any alert because for `driver.switch_to_alert()` I get the error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/alert.py", line 67, in text
    return self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_GET_ALERT_TEXT)["value"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert
```

Comment: For the input, are you using some sort of a modal or a modified version of the javascript prompt?

Comment: No absolutely not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code below is incorrect since it's not handling the prompt alert explicitly.

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys('skdkds')
actions.perform()
```

Change it as follows

```
actions.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Username");
actions.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Password");
```

Comment: Indeed this seems to be the Idea. The equivalent Python code is: `driver.switch_to_alert()`, however I get the error: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert`. I have updated the question

Comment: You are getting this error since the alert that you are using is not a javascript window prompt alert. The code will only work if you use the `prompt` js method, see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_prompt). You may consider using either a modal or use 2 windows prompt that sequentially ask for the username and password.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Just perhaps a silly question: if I don't have the code of the modal, than I can't do anything ? Because this is actually my case here

Comment: That's my understanding if I am honest. I have also tried to use test recorder such as katalon and still, that failed. As it's a bank they sometimes deploy this technique to avoid automated logins for security reasons as prevent non-legitimate login requests. Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if it has helped you.