# How to enter value in browser alert in RobotFramework

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

```
Input Text Into Alert    admin    action=username
```

[image]

I want to know how to enter the username and password . I cannot find the xpath also for this.

Comment: I answered a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496455/selenium-log-in-on-pop-up-webpage-without-html/60496826#60496826) a while ago. We concluded that it wasn't possible. Please do let me know if you do find a solution.

Comment: Its not alert box but HTTP basic authentication popup, you can not automate it using selenium alone. You can use AutoIt to traverse that popup with robotframework. There is also one alternate way discussed here. https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this pop up by putting authentication parameters in application URL,

example: https://username:password@application_url

Comment: The only consistent workaround is to use AutoItLibrary with custom firefox profile. 
`1. First create your own firefox profile (google how to create). 
2. Then launch firefox with the new profile created, and launch the <url> you want to test.
3. When the authorization alert come out, manually input the username & password and click enter or proceed.  This will save the username & password to this browser cache/cookie.. 
4. Next, on RIDE -> 
Open Browser <url> firefox ff_profile_dir=${your_new_profile_dir}
Sleep 2s 
AutoItLibrary.Send {ENTER}`